Is there any node.js implementation available for Reverse Soundex & Reverse NYSIIS?
There are Phonetic Algorithms like "Reverse Soundex" ,"Reverse Nysiis" . We are not able to find anything about its implementation in Node Package Manager website (npjms.com). Can you point us to the implementation of this algorithm in node.js or any pre-built function in node.js.
